# Android NPE on BackdropFrameRenderer onResourcesLoaded()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-graphics

Can anyone tell me the best way to troubleshoot or reproduce this?  All I have is the stack trace, and a bunch of my users are crashing..

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.graphics.drawable.Drawable$ConstantState.newDrawable()' on a null object reference
    at com.android.internal.policy.BackdropFrameRenderer.onResourcesLoaded(BackdropFrameRenderer.java:113)
    at com.android.internal.policy.BackdropFrameRenderer.<init>(BackdropFrameRenderer.java:85)
    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onWindowDragResizeStart(DecorView.java:2041)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.startDragResizing(ViewRootImpl.java:7545)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1981)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1299)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

As you can see, the crash is all in Android API code, so I can't get a good handle on when this is happening.  I found some people have had similar issues but with React Native, and other frameworks.  My app is Java/Kotlin, native code.

Answer (score 0):

A NPE just means that whatever is before the `.` is null. For example `something.DoSomething()` in this case `something` would be null.

In your case, it looks like you're trying to do something with a drawable, but your drawable is null.

Set breakpoints and find out.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, just a tip: The first thing you should try to do is figure out what asset/res/image/whatever is crashing your app, and you can start with actually digging into the source code. For example, [BackdropFrameRenderer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/com/android/internal/policy/BackdropFrameRenderer.java) said that it's about background and resizing, so you can start with looking into places where you set the background, and then try to resize the window (toggle split screen, rotation, or even windows mode in Android Q), and see if you can get more information.

Comment: could this be caused by using `android:elevation` instead of `app:elevation` ?